# clicking button on custom UITableViewCell throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have a custom UITableViewCell (ReservationsCell.h/ReservationsCell.m/ReservationsCell.xib) with a button in it among other things. In the NIB file, the identifier is set as `reservationsCell`, the File's Owner is set as the View Controller, and custom class is set as `ReservationsCell`. The TouchUpInside event of the button in linked to an IBAction written in the ViewController file.

**Problem**

when I click the button, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x398e7ff0`

**Attempts**

The last few hours has taught me to try out NSZombies and that told me that the error was caused by my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

**Code**

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    .....    

    // register ReservationCell nib
    [self.reservationsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ReservationsCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"reservationsCell"];   
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"reservationsCell";
    ReservationsCell *cell = (ReservationsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    ......
}
```

According to Zombies, the specific row that throws the error seems to be `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Please help me. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: post your didSelectRowAtIndexPath code!

Comment: @PremKumar Unfortunately I didnt even have that method implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that your `UIButton`s are defined within reused instances of `UITableViewCell` and therefore might be attached to `UITableViewCell` instances that were already released and deallocated.

What you should do is take care of `IBAction`s in the `UITableViewCell` itself (`ReservationsCell` in your case). These touch events should be forwarded to the `UIViewController` that's coordinating things via delegation (if you need the cell index, pass it along as well).

Good luck!

Comment: I am pretty new to Objective C, could you kindly point me to a tutorial that does the delegation, please?

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556148/use-ibaction-from-uibutton-inside-custom-cell-in-main-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the FilesOwner in a custom `UITableViewCell` nib - it causes weird problems, among them this error you are seeing. Set the custom class for the cell itself, wire your UI outlets up, and have code in the custom `UITableViewCell` class do the work (or delegate the work to its owning `UITableView`).