# How to trigger segue from a custom UITableViewCell - iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, segue, xcode5

Here I have a problem figuring out to trigger a segue from within a custom UITableViewCell.

The thing is that I have implemented an 'edit' UIButton that would pass on the NSIndexPath of the UITableViewCell to the next ViewController in order to edit some entities from Core Data.

Therefore, all the methods and IBActions link are implemented inside the UITableViewClass, not in the UITableViewClass as usual. Normally, I would trigger `[self performSegue: withIdentifier:]` from the ViewController.m file, but here since the IBAction method is implemented inside the UITableViewCell.m file, there's no way to access its ViewController; which later makes the `[self performSegue: withIdentifier:]` impossible.

I think this is quite common, but I still couldn't come up with a good idea to solve this problem. Do you have any strategy regarding this issue?

Comment: I would suggest linking the action of the 'edit' button to the ViewController.m ... or is there an issue that's causing you to not to do so?

Comment: Is it appropriate to do so? Since I have all other UIImageViews, UILabels, and few other stuffs implemented inside the custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: I don't see why not... But I don't think its the best practice... You can refer to this question for another solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556148/use-ibaction-from-uibutton-inside-custom-cell-in-main-view-controller

Hope I helped, and if you have any more questions don't hesitate to ask :)

Comment: Thanks @Mr_bem, of course your answer was helpful. I was thinking about using delegates as well.

Comment: sure! glad it was, good luck! ;D

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a callback block for small things like this because it's less verbose than delegation:

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) void(^tapHandler)();
- (IBAction)buttonTapped;
@end

#import "MyCell.h"
@implementation MyCell

- (void)buttonTapped
{
    if (self.tapHandler) {
        self.tapHandler();
    }
}

@end
```

Then you set the tap handler when you configure the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = ...;
    [cell setTapHandler:^{
        //tap handling logic
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy, but it would be impossible to pass on the NSIndexPath via using block, I assume?

Comment: @Kann No. Blocks can be defined with arguments, giving the caller an opportunity to pass data into the block. But you don't need to do that. The block has access to the local variables where it is defined.  So, inside the block, you can see `tableView`, `indexPath`, `cell` and even `self` (the table view controller). Take a look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not quite used to using blocks in Objective-C yet. I have been tempted to utilize it many times, but it still confuses me sometime. Gonna have a look at the documentation. Thanks again!